# Issue with Json parsing using rest api Expected JSON object to deserialize apex parameter from at [line:4, column:7] errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

Tags: rest-api, rest

``I have a rest service which is reading a json string which is below listed. I am testing this through workbench and i am getting the following error.

> Expected JSON object to deserialize apex parameter from at [line:4,
>   column:7] errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

How do we debug this?

```
 {
      "courses":  
      [
        {
          "CourseId" : "301",
          "CourseName" : "Basic Hardwood Installation"
        },
        {
          "CourseId" : "401",
          "CourseName" : "Advanced Hardwood Installation"
        }
      ]
}
```

Here is my deserialized code. I was wondering whether i can deserialize the entire json in one code or should i be looping to get the value i want?

```
enter code here
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(courses);
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    // Start at the array of invoices.
    if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            // Advance to the start object marker to
            //  find next invoice statement object.
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                // Read entire invoice object, including its array of line items.
                CoursesWrapper courseWrapperObj = (CoursesWrapper)parser.readValueAs(CoursesWrapper.class);
                system.debug('Course Id: ' + courseWrapperObj.courseId);
                system.debug('CourseName: ' + courseWrapperObj.courseName);
                // For debugging purposes, serialize again to verify what was parsed.
                /*String s = JSON.serialize(inv);
                system.debug('Serialized invoice: ' + s);
                */

                // Skip the child start array and start object markers.
                parser.skipChildren();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your object look like your trying to deserliaze into?

Comment: While the main answer's been answered, I would advise that you never, *ever* use JSONParser. It's more of a portability class. JSON.deserialize and JSON.deserializeUntyped is all you should need under normal circumstances. I've never found a case where JSONParser is easier or less verbose than JSON.deserializeUntyped in a worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost end of day for me and I don't check this on the weekends usually, so I'm guessing your class that your deserilizing into is wrong, I think this would work for that response.

```
public class Courses
{
    public Courses()
    {
        courses = new List<CoursesData>();
    }

    public List<CoursesData> courses {get; set};
}

public class CoursesData 
{
    public String CourseId {get; set};  
    public String CourseName {get; set};        
}
```

Testing in execute anonymous

```
String json = '{"courses":[{"CourseId":"301","CourseName":"Basic Hardwood Installation"},{"CourseId":"401","CourseName":"Advanced Hardwood Installation"}]}';
Courses result = new Courses();
result = (Courses)System.JSON.deserialize(json,  Courses.class);   
system.debug('result ' + result);   
public class Courses
{
    public Courses()
    {
        courses = new List<CoursesData>();
    }

    public List<CoursesData> courses {get; set;}
}

public class CoursesData 
{
    public String CourseId {get; set;}  
    public String CourseName {get; set;}        
}
```

Yields

```
DEBUG|result Courses:[courses=(CoursesData:[CourseId=301, CourseName=Basic Hardwood Installation], CoursesData:[CourseId=401, CourseName=Advanced Hardwood Installation])]
```

Comment: Your CoursesData/Courses classes are far too verbose. There's no need for getters, setters, or constructors.

Comment: @sfdcfox I get and set so in the future if there is a change there will be no impact for the consumer,  I also build the constructor so CoursesData will never be null, but technically there is no need, it's personal preference